# Do table names in Excel that end with digit have an undocumented minimum length limit?

Tags: excel, excel-tables, excel-365

While generating a table via CSV import, I noticed that Excel added to some table names an ending underscore: e.g. `abc12.csv` became `Table abc12_`. This does not seem to be consistent with official rules laid out here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rename-an-excel-table-fbf49a4f-82a3-43eb-8ba2-44d21233b114

After many tries, I figured out that table names can be as short as 1 character if they contain only [a-z], however, once a digit is added at the end, a minimum of 5 characters is accepted. And if there are more digits, even more

Eg: name `Table a` is acceptable. Name `Table a1` is NOT acceptable. The shortest acceptable name is `Table abcd1`. However `Table a1234` is NOT acceptable either, the shortest acceptable name is `Table a1234567`.

Is there any documentation that describes this behavior and other rules for the usage of characters and digits in table names in detail? Or is what I described just an undocumented bug?

Comment: On the site you refer to the second point is: `Don’t use cell references — Names can’t be the same as a cell reference, such as Z$100 or R1C1.` So the behaviour is consistent to it.

Comment: @Blackcat: *excellent* find. I've added that to my answer just for completeness.

Comment: @Blackcat: looks very plausible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with not confusing these table names with cells. For example, if you're limited to 16,384 columns, `a` through `xfd`, it makes sense that `abcd1` cannot refer to a cell since `abcd` is *after* `xfd`.

Similarly, `a1234567` cannot be a cell reference since the row count is limited to 1,048,576. But `a1234` definitely *can* be a cell.

Both `a1` and `a1234` (the two ones you give as problematic) could refer to cells. That's also supported by your `a/a1` case: `a` is not a cell but `a1` is.

The easiest way to check this by having two import files, `xfd1.csv` and `xfe1.csv`. Then see what happens when you import them.

In fact, I've just done that (albeit in Office 2013) and found it resulted in the two tables `xfd1_` and `xfe1`. So that *does* appear to confirm it as the reason.

---

So *why* is this needed? Think of what would happen if the (mythical) "'Always Be Closing' Sales" company had an Excel spreadsheet containing all their income for each year (in a single workbook for simplicity).

It would therefore have a named two-dimensional table `abc2023` that contained all their income for that particular year, where each row of the table contains a single month, and each column of the table contains the day within that month.

What would Excel be expected to give you when you enter the formula `=sum(abc2023)` somewhere else in your workbook? Should it just add up the single *cell* `abc2023` or should it sum all cells in the *table* `abc2023`?

The question is obviously moot since Excel *disallows* a table called `abc2023` (or any other potential cell reference clash) but that's almost certainly *why* it disallows it.

---

As to where it's documented, the very page you link to has this bullet point under `Important notes for names`:

- **Don’t use cell references** — Names can’t be the same as a cell reference, such as `Z$100` or `R1C1`.

Comment: Can see the same error when just renaming a table in the worksheet. This answer fits the test of trying to name a table `xfd1` or `xfe1`, `a1048576` or `a1048577`. Interesting that it is a different error message than when trying to name a table as a user-defined named range.

Comment: Also true when naming parameters in LAMBDA expressions: eg `=LAMBDA(d1,d2,d1+d2)` won't work, but `=LAMBDA(d_1,d_2,d_1+d_2)` will

Comment: Looks very plausible, at least within the scope of my experiments. I'll mark this as solution.